# How to connect to CRM in C# console app as the executing user

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to write a console app in C# for Dynamics CRM, using the updated "simplified connection" (using a connection string with CrmServiceClient).  We are running CRM On-Premise, with IFD enabled.

I can get this to work just fine if I hard code the credentials into the connections string, like this:

```
"Url=https://[url]/[orgname];Domain=[domainname];UserName=[username];Password=[password];AuthType=IFD"
```

However, I do not want to hard code the credentials.  I want it to be run as the user running it.  Is there any way to do this?  I tried changing the authtype to AD, and changing to the internal url and removing the login info, but then it won't connect.

Answer (score 0):

While I have never done this myself, according to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn688177.aspx#IFD) you can pass network credentials to one of the CrmServiceClient constructors:

> **Connect to Dynamics 365 Internet-facing deployment (IFD)**
>
> Use the following constructor to connect to a Dynamics 365 IFD
>   instance.
>
> `CrmServiceClient crmSvc = new CrmServiceClient(new
>   System.Net.NetworkCredential("<UserName>", "<Password>", “<Domain>”),
>   AuthenticationType.IFD, "<Server>", "<Port>", "<OrgName>",
>   useUniqueInstance:false, useSsl:false, <orgDetail>);`
>
> This will run a claims-based authentication based on the specified
>   local domain. This is useful for customers that use AD FS, and have
>   configured their Dynamics 365 server as claims, where the user
>   population lives in the same AD FS domain as the Dynamics 365 server.
>   For the  parameter, specify the host name of your Dynamics 365
>   server, for example, crmtest. For the  parameter, you can
>   specify either the unique or friendly name.
>
> The following parameters are optional: useUniqueInstance, useSsl, and
>   orgDetail.

And [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials(v=vs.110).aspx) gives an example of how to get the default credentials from `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`.

```
// Assign the credentials of the logged in user or the user being impersonated.
myHttpWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Comment: Interesting - I hadn't seen the documentation around using a NetworkCredential - everything I was getting revolved around connection strings.  So I tried the above.  Started with just creating a new NetworkCredential based off the hardcoded values, just to make sure I had the syntax.  That was fine.  So then I tried assigning DefaultNetworkCredentials to my credentials variable instead, and I'm getting the exception "When using IFD Authentication you cannot use Default Network, or Default Credentials, or Null.  Create a credential with the users SPLA credentials."  So - not looking good.  :-(

Comment: Thanks for the update. Good to know. It was worth a shot.

Comment: Absolutely!  Thanks for pointing me in a different direction, anyway.  It looked promising.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

With a standard Dynamics CRM IFD installation, normally two URLs are provided - an internal URL which allows for pass-through of the current AD credentials (single sign on) and another, normally external, URL which wraps the connection around ADFS.

To achieve your goal, where the console application has access to the internal URL, select AD authentication, sending the default credentials should work.  However, if your application is not able to access the internal URL, you will need to authenticate with ADFS.   While this is possible, I've not approached this before, as its much simpler to encrypt the password in a configuration file for the console application to read, or provide a UI for the user to enter their username and password.

Comment: Strange.  I definitely tried the internal URL with the AD authtype, and it wouldn't connect.  I'd always gotten the impression that once IFD was on, it was on everywhere, though - the authentication times out after being left open for a long time on the internal URL the same way it does on the external one now.